# subtract a number from its digits until it reaches 0

Tags: algorithms, big-numbers

Can anyone help me with some algorithm for this problem?

We have a big number (19 digits) and, in a loop, we subtract one of the digits of that number from the number itself.

We continue to do this until the number reaches zero. We want to calculate the minimum number of subtraction that makes a given number reach zero.

The algorithm must respond fast, for a 19 digits number ($10^{18}$), within two seconds. As an example, providing input of `36` will give `7`:

```
1. 36 - 6 = 30
2. 30 - 3 = 27
3. 27 - 7 = 20
4. 20 - 2 = 18
5. 18 - 8 = 10
6. 10 - 1 =  9
7.  9 - 9 =  0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which digit gets subtracted?

Comment: Welcome to MSE :) From my experience either this is from an *ongoing competition* or it's your homework. Since this is your first post and it has this particular format, these can somehow guarantee that. To help others help you, please confirm where this question is coming from first, and second tell us what your thoughts are.

Comment: If it is only one number, I think you should subtract the biggest digits always until you get some two-digit number. Then you try to make some smart code for this part.

Comment: probably the biggest digit must be subtracted , because we need minimum subtraction.
yes , it's a homework , i'm not good at math , i discussed this problem with some people and we all agreed that it must be some mathematical problem (because of time limit). so i'll appreciate it if you can help me. thanks

Comment: @Integral that's the brute force approach , it takes so much time to calculate that. it must been some more efficient way. like backtracking or some mathematical formula or something like that.

Comment: You could make a list with this minimum number for all numbers from 10 to $n$, where $n$ is a number that fits in your code and in the memory. You do brutal force until you reach some number $\leq n$, then you use your list to know how more many steps you need, without calculating them.

Comment: That is the best I've got. If you need more and better ideas, try to improve your question to call some attention.

Comment: @Integral thank you , but i don't think that would work, i got 64 MB RAM limit too , that's a hard HW :(

Comment: Also posted to stackoverflow, without notice to either site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696913/subtract-a-numbers-digits-from-the-number-until-it-reaches-0

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is probably cheating.

Comment: Here's the competition it comes from: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/331/C1 Perhaps someone who is registered on stackoverflow can let them know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes , i posted it on stackoverflow first , some people answered somethings an no one can't solve it , someone suggested to ask it on math.stackexchange and i did that. becuase it must be something math related.
and about cheating , its for a homework not for competition , it's kinda is cheating and kinda not, because in stackoverflow everyone said it's almost impossible to solve in given time , so how can i solve that?
but thanks for codeforces reference anyway :)

Comment: For future reference: when you post something to two sites, you **ALWAYS** leave a link to each post at the other one. When you post a problem you didn't make up yourself, you **ALWAYS** cite the source. And when you feel inclined to cheat, **FIRST** turn off your computer.